# Play Framework - Render list of Objects - Not Found in the View

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I got a list of objects that should be read in the "view", but I received the error: **not found: type Workitem.**

How can I read the list of object in my "view"?

Thanks,
Alan Martins

**Controller:**

```
public static Result Divergency() {
    WorkitemManager wim = new WorkitemManager();
    List<Workitem> divergencyList = wim.getDivergencyList();
    return ok(views.html.divergency.render(divergencyList ));
}
```

**View:**

```
@(divergencyList: List[Workitem])

<tfoot>
    @for(divergency<- divergencyList) {
        <tr>
        <th><a href="">@divergency.getId()</a></th>
        <th><a href="">@divergency.getAssigned()</a></th>
        <th><a href="">@divergency.getStatus()</a></th>
    </tr>
    }
</tfoot>
```

**Model:**

```
@Entity
public class Workitem {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String status;
    private String assigned;

    //Getters and Setters

}
```

Comment: Is `Workitem` in `package models`?

Comment: Is this Ebean model? In which package you put it?

Comment: Yes, it's a package model.

Comment: I've moved the Package Model Workitem to the Package Controller, so the Class was found. Should I move it or is there another way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view.scala.html file you have to assign full package name for your Model class

`@(divergencyList: List[com.Beans.Workitem])`

the problem is that play cannot find the Model directly by the name you have to assign full package name.